# How to make XML values comma separated using XPath, XQuery in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have an XML column with sample values as

```
<error>
  <errorno>BL04002055</errorno>
  <description>Smart Rule PROJECT_COUNTRYCODE_VAL Violated</description>
  <description2>Country Code is required</description2>
  <correction />
</error>
<error>
  <errorno>BL01001973</errorno>
  <description />
  <description2>Error While Saving the Project info</description2>
  <correction />
</error>
<error>
  <errorno>Unable to Create Custom Object</errorno>
  <description />
  <description2>Smart Rule PROJECT_COUNTRYCODE_VAL Violated: Country Code is required
Error While Saving the Project info</description2>
  <correction />
</error>
```

I want to select description2 values comma separated

```
select *
--, Response.value(''/error/description2/text()'', 'varchar(8000)') as parsedString
, Response.query('/error/description2/text()') as parsedString
 from #temp
```

Two problems here.

1. I am not able to run value function in query above.
2. Using query, I get values concatenated without space or comma. So I need to add some space or comma on concatenated values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server does not implement the xPath function `string-join`, so you would need to adopt a two step process, the first would be to extract all the terms to rows using `nodes()`;

```
SELECT  n.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS parsedString
FROM    #temp AS t
        CROSS APPLY t.Response.nodes('/error/description2') r (n);
```

Which gives you your values as rows:

```
parsedString
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Country Code is required
Error While Saving the Project info
Smart Rule PROJECT_COUNTRYCODE_VAL Violated: Country Code is required
Error While Saving the Project
```

Then you can add your delimeter and concatenate them back up, using `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE`, and finally use `STUFF` to remove the first delimeter:

```
SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + n.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS parsedString
                FROM    #temp AS t
                        CROSS APPLY t.Response.nodes('/error/description2') r (n)
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS ParsedString;
```

---

**FULL WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
DECLARE @X XML = '<error>
  <errorno>BL04002055</errorno>
  <description>Smart Rule PROJECT_COUNTRYCODE_VAL Violated</description>
  <description2>Country Code is required</description2>
  <correction />
</error>
<error>
  <errorno>BL01001973</errorno>
  <description />
  <description2>Error While Saving the Project info</description2>
  <correction />
</error>
<error>
  <errorno>Unable to Create Custom Object</errorno>
  <description />
  <description2>Smart Rule PROJECT_COUNTRYCODE_VAL Violated: Country Code is required
Error While Saving the Project info</description2>
  <correction />
</error>';

SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + n.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS parsedString
                FROM    (SELECT @X) AS t (Response)
                        CROSS APPLY t.Response.nodes('/error/description2') r (n)
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS ParsedString;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use combination of XQuery `for` and `if..else` statements to construct comma-separated value :

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 'your xml string here'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),
            @xml.query('
                    for $e in error
                    return
                        if($e is /error[last()])
                            then string($e/description2[1])
                        else concat($e/description2[1], ", ")
                    ')
       ) As ParsedString
```

**<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2043)</kbd>**

**brief explanation :**

The XQuery simply iterate through `error` elements and return child element `description2` only if current `error` element is the last `error` element. Otherwise, return `description2` value concatenated with comma.