# Get XML nodes values with a carriage return using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

How to get the value of '`note`' tag value with a carriage return?
Here is my code:

```
declare @Input xml='<Root>
  <Addresses>
    <Address>
      <note>AAA</note>
    </Address>
    <Address>
      <note>BBB</note>
    </Address>
    <Address>
      <note>CCC</note>
    </Address>
    <Address>
      <note>DDD</note>
    </Address>    
  </Addresses>
</Root>'

 SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max),m.c.query('.//Address/note/text()')) AS Comment   
 FROM @Input.nodes('Root/Addresses') AS m ( c )
```

I am expecting a result like below instead of `'AAABBBCCCDDD'`

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30849052/1048425) is pretty similar and should help, the only difference appears to be the other question wants a comma as the delimiter whereas you require a carriage return.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this to get desired result:

```
declare @Result nvarchar(max)

select @Result = isnull(@Result + char(13) + char(10), '') + m.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @Input.nodes('Root/Addresses/Address/note') as m(c)

select @Result
```

Comment: I was expecting the result as same as GarethD mentioned in the comment. Anyways thank you for your solution.

Comment: @Pradeep oh, I haven't figured out what you need to concatenate your values in one string having newline as delimiter. I've updated my answer with alternative approach - have a look, maybe it will fit your requirement.